# AngularJS - regex for zip code like 11-111

Tags: regex, angularjs

why the following regex for matching zip code like `11-111` doesn't work ?

```
<input type="text" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}$/" required />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From ng-pattern docs:

> Sets pattern validation error key if the value does not match the RegExp pattern expression. Expected value is /regexp/ for inline patterns or regexp for **patterns defined as scope expressions**.

try set a scope variable:

```
$scope.regex = "/^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}$/"
```

and change the pattern input

```
<input type="text" ng-pattern="regex" required />
```

Comment: as you quoted in the documentation it is 'regexp' in the scope not '/regexp/'. Try with $scope.regex = "^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}$"

Answer (score 0):

If what I suggested in my comment is not enough then, this JsFiddle is doing what you want 
http://jsfiddle.net/wkzab/4/

It seems the main difference is the 'i' at the end of the regexp.

```
ng-pattern="/^[A-Z]{4}\d{6}[A-Z\d]{3}$/i"
```